# pandas: one-to-many operation on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join, one-to-many, cross-apply

I have a pandas dataframe such that

```
     GROUP_ID  USER_ID     USER_NAME     
0         65        50         ABC1  
1         65        74         ABC2  
2         69        71         ABC3
```

Let's say I have another dataframe df2 with just one record and subset of columns

```
      USER_ID     USER_NAME     
0         007         BOND
```

What I want is to have a one-to-many relationship from df2 to df1 on the `GROUP_ID` so that

```
     GROUP_ID  USER_ID     USER_NAME     
0         65        50         ABC1
1         65       007         BOND
2         65        74         ABC2 
3         69        71         ABC3
4         69       007         BOND
```

I suppose this is equivalent of a sql CROSS APPLY. As always, any help or guidance is appreciated

Comment: It's a bit unclear what functionality you want. Do you want each row in df1 to be followed by the row from df2, with all columns not in df2 to be filled in with the row from df1?

Comment: The order doesn't matter to me. I just want a record from df2 have all records in df1 for each GROUP_ID

Answer (score 2):

`pd.concat` +`ffill`

```
    pd.concat([df,pd.concat([df1]*len(df)).set_index(df.index)]).sort_index().ffill()
Out[1327]: 
   GROUP_ID  USER_ID USER_NAME
0      65.0       50      ABC1
0      65.0        7      BOND
1      67.0       74      ABC2
1      67.0        7      BOND
2      69.0       71      ABC3
2      69.0        7      BOND


pd.concat([df,pd.concat([df1] * df.GROUP_ID.nunique().reset_index(drop=True)]).sort_index().bfill()
Out[1418]: 
   GROUP_ID  USER_ID USER_NAME
0      65.0       50      ABC1
0      65.0        7      BOND
1      65.0       74      ABC2
1      69.0        7      BOND
2      69.0       71      ABC3
```

Comment: Please see my edits in the question. I forgot to add one aspect that the GROUP_ID can repeat themselves for different USER. So in your solution, BOND repeats itself multiple times for the same GROUP_ID. I suppose I could just remove the duplicates after this operation but I was wondering if there's a better approach

Comment: @wen I remember using the same line somewhere I don't know where.

Comment: @Fizi sry for the late reply on my phone .

Comment: @Bharath I just back to the office ... plz undelete yours

Comment: Ohk, but they are bit identical.

Comment: @Bharath that still not the same , no worry

Answer (score 1):

Lets use merge with concat i.e

```
x =  df1['GROUP_ID'].unique()
ndf= df1.merge(pd.concat([df2]*len(x)).assign(GROUP_ID=x),how='outer')
```

Output :

```
  GROUP_ID  USER_ID USER_NAME
0        65       50      ABC1
1        65       74      ABC2
2        69       71      ABC3
3        65        7      BOND
4        69        7      BOND
```

This can also be done with concat  i.e

```
ndf = pd.concat([df1,pd.concat([df2]*len(x)).assign(GROUP_ID=x)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```